# Processing variable fixed size groups of work in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I find myself wanting to write CUDA code similar to:

```
__constant__ int cumulativeGroupThreadCount[GroupCount];

__device__ int SearchForGroupIndex()
{
    int gridThreadID = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int groupIndex = 0;
    int sum = 0;


    while(groupIndex < GroupCount && gridThreadID <= sum)
    {
        sum += cumulativeGroupThreadCount[groupIndex];
        ++groupIndex;
    }

    return groupIndex;
}

__device__ KernelMain()
{
    GroupData data = groupData[SearchForGroupIndex()];

    ...
}
```

With the intent to process groups of data, where each group may be of a different size, but I wish to process each group item using one CUDA thread.  Where each group has a specific associated piece of group data.

If the number of groups isn't that large then I am supposing it's possibly not the worst approach?

As the number of groups increases I can begin to think of more complicated warp/block wide binary search type behaviour but I get the feeling that it wouldn't be such a good idea at that point.

Another approach could be to sort/bucket each group by size, then process each group with the same size with a dispatch each.  Or a variation on that where a maximum of the items per group is taken, resulting in possibly multiple useless threads that need to be masked out.  Potentially splitting into multiple batches to minimise the wastage.

A simpler approach is of course to store an index to the group data per thread but that potentially could waste more space and memory bandwidth then needed?

So is there a better way to approach this type of problem generally in CUDA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary search should work well. It will have good memory locality because neighboring threads will be in the same or neighboring groups, and branch divergence will be minimal if the average group size is large relative to the warp size.

Something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename I>
__device__
I upper_bound_index(T const* data,
                    I        count,
                    T const& value) {
    I start = 0;
    while( count > 0 ) {
        I step = count / 2;
        if( !(value < data[start + step]) ) {
            start += step + 1;
            count -= step + 1;
        } else {
            count = step;
        }
    }
    return start;
}

__global__
void group_kernel(int                           numGroups,
                  int       const* __restrict__ cumulativeGroupThreadCount,
                  GroupData const* __restrict__ groupData) {
    int gridThreadID = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int groupID = upper_bound_index(cumulativeGroupThreadCount,
                                    numGroups,
                                    gridThreadID);
    if( groupID == numGroups ) {
        // Excess threads
        return;
    }
    int itemID = gridThreadID - (groupID > 0 ?
                                 cumulativeGroupThreadCount[groupID-1] :
                                 0);
    GroupData data = groupData[groupID];
    // ...
}
```